# Changing the visibility hidden and call fadeIn() when click event occured

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display an element(calling fadeIn function) when click event is occured. But, I want to do it on an element which is not visible at the first load. When the user click on it, it will be displayed and will be there unless the page refreshes. Codes;

```
<input type="text" name="q" size="40" 
maxlength="255" class = "send"/>

<h6 style = "position:absolute;top:48px;left:43%;color:white;" class = "displayIt">DisplayMe</h6>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".send").bind("click",function(){
    $(".displayIt").css("visibility","visible").fadeIn(2000);
  });    
});
</script>
```

When i do this, fadeIn does not work because it makes the element(displayIt) visible suddenly:( How can i display it as implemented in fadeIn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As fadeIn just plays with `opacity` of the element, making it visible will right away show it.  So before you starts fading hide the element.

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wbeNb/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".send").bind("click",function(){
    $(".displayIt").css("visibility","visible").hide().fadeIn(2000);
  });    
});
```

Comment: That worked,thx:)But i am confused now.Can you explain why we did need hide()? As i know, hide function was used to hide something, not display. Show() did not work for example...

Comment: When we hide the element it sets `display` property of element style to `none`. What `fadeIn` does is, it changes the `opacity` of the element style from 0 to 1 but before it starts changing it shows the element.