# Using li elements and links not refreshing

Tags: jquery, slider

I've started a homemade slider function while learning the basics of jquery. The slider works, it changes everything contained in the `<li>` tags going from one to the next. Only problem, while my content changes the links send me back to the last entry. When I load the page it sends me at first to the first entry but as soon as the slider works once it always sends me to the last entry.

Here's my function : http://pastebin.com/MXQrnmY0
And a jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/t4ySm

Comment: Can you create a demo using http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t4ySm/ Here it is doesn't work quite like the original but it'll do to show the problem :) Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is using fadeTo, which only change the opacity of the `<li>` stack. Since its to be seen as a stack, the top (latest added) link "covers" all links under it (it just makes all items in the stack transparent).

You want to change css-style `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visibile;` property. See this question for example: [Changing the visibility hidden and call fadeIn() when click event occured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338977/changing-the-visibility-hidden-and-call-fadein-when-click-event-occured)

Comment: Thank you very much, I was quite stuck and your answer makes perfect sense.